# Find owner of Linux DIRECTORY ONLY

Tags: linux, find

I have a python program that makes a ssh query to a linux server like so:
`find . -type d > myfile.txt`

A single line of output looks something like:

> /Downloads/SomeDirectory/

I also need the owner name of the directory (only), and NOT files,listed next to the directory name, like so:

> johndoe /Downloads/SomeDirectory/
> OR
> /Downloads/SomeDirectory/ johndoe

I do NOT want the information of the files in the directories to be included in the file, just the directory owner and the paths like mentioned above.

My current approach is to make an ssh request for every single directory with `ls -la directorypath` and then parsing out the owner, but it takes a long time since I have thousands of directories.
How should I go about this? I do NOT want to make thousands of SSH requests.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
find . -type d -printf '%p %u\n' > myfile.txt
```

- `%p` - file / directory name
- `%u` - owner

Comment: It's NOT writing to the file

Comment: @HarshitJindal `find . -type d -printf '%p %u\n' > myfile.txt` is not writing to the file?

Comment: No, it just makes a blank file. If I try to run the command without redirection to file, then I can see all the output on STDOUT

Comment: I do get content in my file, running the very same command. Try it as it is in a local shell. Perhaps your issue has something to do with the way you call it, from python and via ssh?

Comment: Also, are you sure you are letting it run until the end, without interrupting it?

Comment: Remember: terminal output is normally line-buffered (the output is flushed at every line), while file redirection is fully buffered (the output is flushed at the end). So if you stop if before it ended, you get nothing.
You can test this by forcing line-buffering: `stdbuf -oL find . -type d -printf '%p %u\n' > myfile.txt`. This should allow you to stop early and still get content in your file.

Comment: I'm sorry, it started working. Probably had to do something with my internet connection. Heavy rain started and I lost connection on that device. Doesn't fully make sense, but idk.. Apologies again